# Stop Execution of angular $timeout after $http interceptor is called

Tags: angularjs, timeout, interceptor

I am using $httpProvider.interceptors to catch a 401 or 403 request, after which i end the session and redirect to the login page. There is a function which has a timeout function, i want to stop this timeout from executing if i get a 401 or 403 response

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel a timeout rather easily

```
var myTimeout = $timeout(function() {}, 1000);
// Check http status code
if (someHttpCode === 401){
  // Stop the timeout
  $timeout.cancel(myTimeout);
}
```

Comment: The ability to cancel is not 'due to the fact it returns a promise'. In general there is no way to cancel a promise, this is an extra feature added to the promise by the timeout.
Also worth noting recent versions of angularjs don't require you to pass an empty function, you can just call `$timeout(1000)` to get the promise.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for the correction, I'll bare that in mind

Comment: i know we can cancel a timeout by saving it in a variable, i just wanted to know whether there is a global method that just flushes out all the pending timeout at once without saving it in any variable

Comment: No, as far as i'm aware there is no global clear all timeouts for angularjs, you will need to use the method i've shown above

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$timeout.cancel(timer)` to stop a timer.

Read more about it here in the docs: 
[$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: You should provide some context and explanation in your answer not just a link to the documentation. Also quote the relevant part of the documentation in case the link becomes invalid in the future. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to save timer, like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp):

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

Comment: that's why i left link to w3?

Comment: i don't know why you think you need to highlight it

Comment: Downvoted because the question was clearly about angular so it is not appropriate to use `setTimeout`.